# When user Facebook "like"s my page, I want them to also "like" my (separate) FB fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My site, http://flashlightworthybooks.com, has a series of highly-specific book lists ("Best Mystery Books for 2010," "Best Children's Books about Dealing with Cancer," etc.). Right now a user can click the "like" button on any of these lists and their Facebook wall will get a message like "Eric likes 'Best Mystery Books for 2010'". So far, so good.

I also have a Facebook fan page specifically for Flashlight Worthy. If people go to that page, and "like" it, then my updates on that page show up in their stream on Facebook. This is good. I want this.

My question: when someone clicks "like" on a specific book list, I want to keep the existing behavior, posting their "like" of that specific list on their individual FB wall. But I'd also like them to automatically "like" my FB fan page at the same time.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or something similar?

Update: to be clear, I'm not trying to do anything shady here. I'm trying to solve a structural issue that I've seen on other sites as well as my site: I want to let people "like" a specific page on my site (so it will promote that page to their friends, on their FB wall), and I also want them to "like" my fan page on FB (so I can continue the communication with them). Maybe the solution isn't to automatically "like" both pages at once... I'm really open to creative ideas to help me reach both of my goals. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a security hole if possible? "When someone likes my [video of otters holding hands](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epUk3T2Kfno), I'd like them to automatically like the [Comic Sans cafe](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/web/fonts/comicsns/default.htm) at the same time."

Comment: Thanks for the reply-- I suppose it could be a security hole, if you wanted to look at it that way.... I'd be fine with disclosing what was going on, of course, and I'm not trying to do anything shady. Let's not get sidetracked on the "morality of the functionality" though :-) Maybe the right answer to my question isn't to like both pages at once, but to somehow prompt the user to like the face page after the list page, or something. I'm open to ideas!

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter whether *you* want to do something shady with this or not - a feature like this would definitely enable some very shady things to happen.

Comment: Sure, I can see where you're coming from. That's why I said I'm open to other ideas to help meet the goal.

Answer (score 1):

I hope not. Clicking "Like" on one page should not automatically "like" their peadophile page, too.